# saving a list of rows to a Hive table in pyspark

Tags: python, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark app.  I copied a hive table to my hdfs directory, & in python I `sqlContext.sql` a query on this table. Now this variable is a dataframe I call `rows`.  I need to randomly shuffle the `rows`, so I had to convert them to a list of rows `rows_list = rows.collect()`.  So then I `shuffle(rows_list)` which shuffles the lists in place.   I take the amount of random rows I need `x`:

`for r in range(x):
        allrows2add.append(rows_list[r])`

Now I want to save allrows2add as a hive table OR append an existing hive table (whichever is easier to do).  The problem is that I can not do this:

`all_df = sc.parallelize(allrows2add).toDF()` Cant do this, schema can't be inferred
`ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined by the first 100 rows, please try again with sampling`

without putting in the whole schema.  The schema of `rows` has 117 columns, so I don't want to type them out.  Is there a way to extract the schema of `rows` to help me make allrows2add a dataframe or somehow save as a hive table?
I can do 
`rows.printSchema()` but not sure how to get it into a schema format as a variable to pass `toDF()` without having to parse all of that text

Thanks

Adding for loop info

```
#Table is a List of Rows from small Hive table I loaded using
#query = "SELECT * FROM Table"
#Table = sqlContext.sql(query).collect()

for i in range(len(Table)):

    rows = sqlContext.sql(qry)
    val1 = Table[i][0]
    val2 = Table[i][1]
    count = Table[i][2]
    x = 100 - count

#hivetemp is a table that I copied from Hive to my hfs using:
#create external table IF NOT EXISTS hive temp LIKE hivetableIwant2copy LOCATION "/user/name/hiveBackup";
#INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE hivetemp SELECT * FROM hivetableIwant2copy;

    query = "SELECT * FROM hivetemp WHERE col1<>\""+val1+"\" AND col2 ==\""+val2+"\" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT "+str(x)

    rows = sqlContext.sql(query)
    rows = rows.withColumn("col4", lit(10))
    rows = rows.withColumn("col5", lit(some_string))
#writing to parquet is heck slow AND I can't work with pandas due to the library not installed on the server
    rows.saveAsParquetFile("rows"+str(i)+".parquet")
#tried this before and heck slow also
    #rows_list = rows.collect()
    #shuffle(rows_list)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When the schema can't be inferred, there's usually a reason. `toDF` is syntactic sugar for the `createDataFrame` function, which by default only uses the first 100 rows ([despite the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame) saying it only uses the first row) to determine what the schema should be. To change this, you can increase the sampling ratio to look at a greater percentage of your data:

```py
df = rdd.toDF(sampleRatio=0.2)
# or...
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, samplingRatio=0.2)
```

It's also possible that your random sample happened to only take rows with empty values for some particular columns. If this is the case, you can either [create a schema from scratch](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame) like so:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
# all DataFrame rows are StructType
# can create a new StructType with combinations of StructField
schema = StructType([
    StructField("column_1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("column_2", IntegerType(), True),
    # etc.
])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=schema)
```

Or, you can get the schema from the previous DataFrame you created by accessing the `schema` value:

```py
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=df1.schema)
```

Note that if your RDD's rows aren't `StructType` (a.k.a. `Row`) objects instead of dictionaries or lists, you won't be able to create a data frame from them. If your RDD rows are dictionaries, you can convert them to `Row` objects like this:

```
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: pyspark.sql.Row(**x))
# ** is to unpack the dictionary since the Row constructor
# only takes keyword arguments
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this works.  I went with accessing the `schema` value.  One thing I am trying to get around is why is this so slow (whether it is converted dataframe to list of rows, or simple things like writing to a parquet file or trying to append a hive table) - but that could be something with my system vs the api itself.

Comment: Without looking at your data/code, I can't be sure. Is your input file split up into partitions? If it's a single partition, then Spark won't parallelize loading.

Comment: I just edit my original post above to show more information.  I am pretty new to Spark, so I am not 100% sure but I loaded my input from a hive table (which I copied from the hive server to my hdfs directory).  If you have any suggestions or can point me to resources (I tried this in Scala also, so Scala code will be fine) - that would be great! Thanks a lot

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not why the saving is taking so long. I recommend you ask a new question, giving these three pieces of info: 1) your code, 2) the number of rows/columns/partitions of your data frame, and 3) the total size (GB, etc.) of the saved data file. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks - I just posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924111/loading-hive-and-writing-results-to-hive-or-parquet-or-csv-very-slow):